# Set customize credits in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How to set custom credits in Highcharts?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Bastss/rwmb6dpy/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  series: [{
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }]
});
```

Any help could be useful.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Wędzel, Please describe the problem more precisely. What you do want to achieve?

Comment: Hi! I want to open a new website after clicking the credits span.

Comment: Could you share the url?

Comment: check api: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/credits

Comment: This the url which I want to open in new tab: http://kotlet.pl/

Comment: Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for asking. You can do it this way: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5h6t4r8u/

```
credits: {
    text: 'kotlet.pl',
    href: 'https://www.google.com/'
  },
```

Comment: Could you check your example? It is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Oh gosh... I found it... I was able to achieve that by using this code:

```
credits: {
    text: 'kotlet.pl',
    href: 'https://www.google.com/'
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/credits.href